# What is the right way to detect multiple occurences of non-whitespaces in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

This must be **true**

```
kword = dontmatter ~~ abc #include
kword = dontmatter ~~ abc#include
kword = dontmatter ~~abc #include
kword = dontmatter ~~ a bc #include
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
/~~\s*[^\s]+\s*#include/.test(kword)
```

The condition is not passing the 4th kword. Why?

Comment: Instead of `[^\s]`, why not just use `\S`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this part `/~~\s*[^\s]+\s*` only matches `~~ a`, so the rest of the string is `bc #include`, which is not matched by `#include`.

`~~\s*[^\s].+?#include` should match what you want. `[^\s].*?` matches a minimum of one character that is not a white space, followed by matching all characters, non-greedy, followed by `#include`.

Comment: @fireflieslive Your suggested edit was rejected as incorrect because `[^\s].+?` would require at least one character between the non-whitespace character and `#include`, so `kword = dontmatter ~~ a#include` would fail. I presume you'd want that to match? If so, it's the regex at the *beginning* of that sentence that should be corrected (the + should be changed to a *), not the other way around.